# Method to stop FFmpeg encoding process & complete uninstall in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg, uninstall

Recently i installed FFmpeg cause i want to convert 10bit H.265  to 8 bit H.264.I found the encoding to be very slow & want to uninstall this software
Also can someone guide me on how to kill/stop the encoding process.
I surfed all articles on uninstalling FFmpeg but there is none regarding Windows.Tried the Make Uninstall in cmd but there is make not recognized message.To stop the encoding process i just closed the cmd window not sure if its the right way.Please help cause i don;t know what's the command line.
My FFmpeg folder is stored at Program Files,also did a path variable at system variable,Browser is Mozilla Firefox

Comment: There's no installation. Simply remove the folder and revert the path variable. I assume you downloaded the Zeranoe build.

Comment: Usual way to abort a ffmpeg process is to press q or Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the application I just delete the FFmpeg folder & go to path variable(system variable) edit to delete the FFmpeg directory path.